# if input is empty then show a picture, or another

Tags: javascript, html

I have an form, like this

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="abc" name="abc" value="abc"><img src="right.png">
    <input type="text" id="abc1" name="abc" value=""><img src="wrong.png">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

but I don't understand how to show this. When the input is not empty `<img src="right.png">` and if it is empty then `<img src="wrong.png">`

Comment: Are you planning to use **JQuery**?

Comment: Anything, that shows the different result, based on input, if it is empty then show wrong, else show right

Comment: Also any elements can not have same `id's`. In your case both `input` elements have same `id="abc"`.

Comment: it was a mistake, and i lost the javacript code (for another topic related with this).and I do not have any code for this

Answer (score 7):

Mark your input `required` and add some CSS, like this:

```css
    input:required:valid::after{
        content: url(path/to/right.png);
    }
    input:required:invalid::after{
        content: url(path/to/wrong.png);
    }
```

```html
    <input type="text" required="required" minlength="1">
```

Fall back on @divy3993's if you have to support some [horrible old browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input$edit#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 5):

I would go with @dtanders but still a simple solution with JavaScript would not harm you.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("abc");
    var curVal = x.value;
    var imageRW = document.getElementById('img_right_wrong');
    if (curVal == "")
    {
    //wrong.png   
      imageRW.src = "http://findicons.com/files/icons/1671/simplicio/128/notification_error.png";
    }
    else
    {
    //right.png
      imageRW.src = "https://d3n7l4wl5znnup.cloudfront.net/assets/images/icon-right.png";
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" id="abc" onkeyup="myFunction()" name="abc" value="">
<img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1671/simplicio/128/notification_error.png" id="img_right_wrong" width="2%">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**Update:**

**<kbd>[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/phwmLdb2/)</kbd>**

Comment: its right almost, but if the value is already filled up then it also show the cross marks

Comment: @ShuvoShuvo Just call the `function` on page load. So here call `myFunction();` on page load.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you want to do dynamic form validation. So you can add event listener And JavaScript:

```js
function checkInput() {
  if ($("#abc").val().length == 0) {
    // change image
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="abc" name="abc" onchange="checkInput()">
```

But using jQuery plugin is better:
[link](http://formvalidation.io/examples/adding-dynamic-field/) (**EDIT**: this link is dead, but it can be found on [the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20180603221501/http://formvalidation.io/examples/adding-dynamic-field/))

Comment: jQuery is overkill for this, and jQuery with a plugin is way, way overkill.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily in `angularjs` using ng-show.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
  <head>
    <title>Chat Application</title>
    <script src="./scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">                  
  </head>
  <body ng-app="chatApp">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="FirstName" ng-model="text" ng-init='text=""'>
      <br />
      <img src="right.png"  alt="right" ng-show="text.length >0">
      <img src="wrong.png" alt="wrong" ng-show="text.length === 0">
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
    </div>
      
    <script src="./scripts/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: umm..why is this downvoted? anything wrong in the answer?